# Push Respond CMS to Heroku: no 'composer.lock' was found

Tags: git, heroku, composer-php, respondcms

I want to host Respond CMS on Heroku, so I did:

1. `git clone` of the respondcms repository
2. `heroku` create in that folder
3. `git push heroku master`

I always get the following error in the terminal:

```
remote: ----->PHP app detected
remote:
remote:  !     ERROR: Your 'composer.json' lists dependencies inside 'require',
remote:        but no 'composer.lock' was found. Please run 'composer update' to
remote:        re-generate 'composer.lock' if necessary, and commit it into your
remote:        repository. For more information, please refer to the docs at
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#activation
remote:
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to app-name
```

I ran `composer update` and that works fine, also there is a `composer.lock` file in the folder.

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `composer.lock` file doesn't just have to exist locally, it has to be *committed*. That way it will be included when you push to Heroku.

Try something like this:

- `git add composer.lock`
- `git commit` using a message like `Add Composer lock file`
- `git push heroku` (or whatever your remote is called)

The reason for this is that `composer.json` generally specifies dependencies in a somewhat vague way, e.g. "whatever the latest 1.2.x release is" or "the latest commits on the `master` branch". You can probably imagine that you and I might get different results depending on when we install our dependencies.

The `composer.lock` file's job is to lock these dependencies down in a more rigorous way. If you install the latest 1.2.x release of a library, its precise version is recorded in `composer.lock`, e.g. "version 1.2.2 at Git hash 1234abc".

In general, unless you are deliberately updating libraries it is better to use `composer`*`install`*, not `composer update`. The former uses the exact versions from the lock file and doesn't update anything. That way we can have more confidence that we are using identical libraries. The latter updates new versions and changes the lock file.

I've never used Heroku with PHP, but it makes sense that it wants to install the exact versions listed in the lock file.

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the trick. I was already guessing something like that. RespondCMS has "composer.lock" in the .gitignore, should I just remove it from there, to prevent this also for further commits? I think also, I should remove the vendor folder from my git repository for a Heroku app, right?

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Now that the lock file is committed, it being in the `.gitignore` won't matter. Git's ignore system only applies to untracked content. Any changes to `composer.lock` will now be recognized by Git. (Though IMO the file probably shouldn't be ignored.)

Comment: Removing `vendor/` is a good idea too. [Heroku will build this for you from the Composer files](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-php#declare-app-dependencies). `git rm -r --cached vendor` should do the trick. (`--cached` will leave the files in your working copy, but stage them to be removed from the repository.) Then add `vendor/` to your `.gitignore`.